# MYSQL C++ Connector: "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier"

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2019, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-c

I've created a C++ windows form application and I want to tie it to a database. However, It keeps giving me an error that I am unable to solve. It highlights my `conn` variable which is of type `MYSQL*` and just gives me this error: `this declaration has no storage class or type specifier`. I have all libraries linked and includes so I don't get what's the issue.

Code:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql.h>

MYSQL* conn;
MYSQL_ROW row;
MYSQL_RES* res;
conn = mysql_init(0);

conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, my host here, my username, my password, my db name, port, NULL, 0);

namespace MSSLogin {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;


    public ref class Login_Panel : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Login_Panel(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:

        ~Login_Panel()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
        private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label1;
        protected:
        private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label2;
        private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button1;
        private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox1;
        private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox2;
        private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^ pictureBox1;
        private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label3;

        protected:

        private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^ resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(Login_Panel::typeid));
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->pictureBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
            this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox1))->BeginInit();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(71, 25);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(90, 18);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->label1->Text = L"Username:";
            this->label1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Login_Panel::label1_Click);
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this->label2->AutoSize = true;
            this->label2->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(71, 56);
            this->label2->Name = L"label2";
            this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(88, 18);
            this->label2->TabIndex = 1;
            this->label2->Text = L"Password:";
            this->label2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Login_Panel::label2_Click);
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(118, 95);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(196, 32);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 2;
            this->button1->Text = L"Login";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Login_Panel::button1_Click);
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(167, 23);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(192, 20);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 3;
            this->textBox1->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Login_Panel::textBox1_TextChanged);
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(167, 56);
            this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
            this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(192, 20);
            this->textBox2->TabIndex = 4;
            this->textBox2->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Login_Panel::textBox2_TextChanged);
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this->pictureBox1->Image = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^>(resources->GetObject(L"pictureBox1.Image")));
            this->pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(364, 146);
            this->pictureBox1->Name = L"pictureBox1";
            this->pictureBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(60, 55);
            this->pictureBox1->SizeMode = System::Windows::Forms::PictureBoxSizeMode::Zoom;
            this->pictureBox1->TabIndex = 5;
            this->pictureBox1->TabStop = false;
            this->pictureBox1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Login_Panel::pictureBox1_Click);
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this->label3->AutoSize = true;
            this->label3->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 183);
            this->label3->Name = L"label3";
            this->label3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(185, 18);
            this->label3->TabIndex = 6;
            this->label3->Text = L"@misrsoftwaresystems";
            this->label3->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Login_Panel::label3_Click);
            // 
            // Login_Panel
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(436, 213);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
            this->FormBorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::FixedSingle;
            this->HelpButton = true;
            this->Icon = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Icon^>(resources->GetObject(L"$this.Icon")));
            this->MaximizeBox = false;
            this->MinimizeBox = false;
            this->Name = L"Login_Panel";
            this->Text = L"Login";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Login_Panel::Login_Panel_Load);
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox1))->EndInit();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
        private: System::Void groupBox1_Enter(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        }
        private: System::Void pictureBox1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        }
        private: System::Void textBox2_TextChanged(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        }
        private: System::Void label1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        }
        private: System::Void label2_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        }
        private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        }
        private: System::Void textBox1_TextChanged(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        }
        private: System::Void label3_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    }
        private: System::Void Login_Panel_Load(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        }

    };
}
```

I've tried moving that block of code constantly in and out of the namespace and the class hoping it would have an effect, but obviously not.

Error Logs:

```
Warning C4829   Possibly incorrect parameters to function main. Consider 'int main(Platform::Array<Platform::String^>^ argv)'   MSS_Login   D:\MSS\MSS_System\MSS_Login\Login_Panel.cpp 7   
Error   C2664   'MYSQL *mysql_real_connect(MYSQL *,const char *,const char *,const char *,const char *,unsigned int,const char *,unsigned long)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'MYSQL *' MSS_Login   D:\MSS\MSS_System\MSS_Login\Login_Panel.h   10  
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    MSS_Login   D:\MSS\MSS_System\MSS_Login\Login_Panel.h   10  
Error   C2374   'conn': redefinition; multiple initialization   MSS_Login   D:\MSS\MSS_System\MSS_Login\Login_Panel.h   10  
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'MYSQL *' to 'int'  MSS_Login   D:\MSS\MSS_System\MSS_Login\Login_Panel.h   8   
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    MSS_Login   D:\MSS\MSS_System\MSS_Login\Login_Panel.h   8   
Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier MSS_Login   D:\MSS\MSS_System\MSS_Login\Login_Panel.h   10  
Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier MSS_Login   D:\MSS\MSS_System\MSS_Login\Login_Panel.h   8
```

Screenshots of my linked `libs` and `includes`:

`C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories`
[First Image of Include Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9sdV.png)

`Linker > General > Additional Library Directories`
[Second Image of Library Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Yzt.png)

`Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies`
[Third Image of Additional Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx8Yj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, it has to be within a function. I misunderstood the error for something else. My bad

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.